# Changing VBA Function for deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA Function where it will find the info typed into the Input Box and deletes every row with that value.

How can I change it to delete all rows except for the value you enter. Example I enter 123. I want it to delete all rows except for the cells in column B with 123.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SrchStr As String

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1", ActiveSheet.Range("B4343").End(xlUp))
    SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter Value")
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK there may well be a better way to do this but I went with creating a temp sheet, copy in the rows that match your search, clear all rows in the sheet and finally copy back the rows that matched then delete the temp sheet:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range, b As Range, SrchRng As Range, SrchStr As String, MasterSheet As Worksheet, TempSheet As Worksheet
    Set MasterSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A4343").End(xlUp))
    SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter Value")
    Worksheets.Add
    Set TempSheet = ActiveSheet
    MasterSheet.Select
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set b = c
    Do
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy
            TempSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
        Set c = SrchRng.FindNext(After:=c)
        If c.Address = b.Address Then Exit Do
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.ClearContents
    TempSheet.Range("A2:A" & TempSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & TempSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

I started playing around trying to populate an array from the search results in one go without looping it but it didn't go well and I have run out of spare time to explore this further unfortunately. My idea was to try and populate an array from the results in one go, then select all rows minus anything in the joined array then delete. Not sure how possible that is but maybe explore it if you get time.

My Test data was using column A, you will need to change a few parts for column B.